# Bootstrap nav tab content display error

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a personal project and using Bootstrap nav-tabs for the first time which seems pretty straight forward, however, after adding in content for the 'History' tab, it's escaping and appears on all the tabs. I've looked over and over the code and missing out where I have wen't wrong. Perhaps a fresh pair of eyes would catch it for me? [Link to screenshot](http://oi67.tinypic.com/6onbba.jpg), [Link to source code](https://codepaste.net/i2852w).

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to increase the likelihood of getting your question answered. Please note that image and code should be provide directly in your question, and not on an external website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the extra two closing `div` in your code. Move the history `tab-pane` inside `tab-content`.

[image]

Comment: @Keiran Your Welcome :)